# Required, request body is missing: public when I try loading Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, http-status-code-400

I am trying to access the swagger URL from my Spring-Boot application using the `post` request. But getting a `400-Bad request` and it says *the request body is missing*. But the same request works fine in Postman.
Controller:

```
@RestController
public class IdVController {

    @Autowired
    private IdService idService;

    @Autowired
    protected FileUtility util;

    /** The Constant STATUS. */
    private static final String STATUS = "status";

    /** The Constant SUCCESS. */
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    /** The Constant SYSTEM. */
    private static final String SYSTEM = "SYSTEM";

    @RequestMapping(value ="/idApi")
    public ResponseEntity<MarketPlaceResponse> 
    validateIdData(@RequestBody  VerifyIdDTO verifyIdDTO) throws Exception {
        JSONObject rawResponse = idService.validateId(verifyIdDTO);

        IdVerifyEntity DTOResponse = (IdVerifyEntity)util.convertToEntity(rawResponse.toString(), IdVerifyEntity.class);
        if (rawResponse.get(STATUS).equals(SUCCESS)) {
            DTOResponse.setCreated_by(SYSTEM);
            DTOResponse.setCreated_date(new 
            java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
        }
        
        //return ResponseBuilder.buildResponse(DTOResponse);
        MarketPlaceResponse response = new MarketPlaceResponse();
        response.setResponse(DTOResponse);

        return new ResponseEntity<MarketPlaceResponse>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Request DTO:

```
public class VerifyIdDTO {

    @NotBlank(message="Owner ID should not be empty")
    private String id;
    private String citizenship;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCitizenship() {
        return citizenship;
    }

    public void setCitizenship(String citizenship) {
        this.citizenship = citizenship;
    }
}
```

I am contacting an external service by building URL and using GET from this POST method
this is the swagger URL
`localhost:8080/idvalidationservice/swagger-ui.html`

You can see the error message in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA5LA.jpg).

Comment: Seems like your swagger URL is incorrect.

Comment: `@RequestBody` is [required by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html#required--), so this is expected behavior…

Comment: welcome to SO. Please don't post error output as images. Search engines can't parse it and it will be inaccessible to users with certain disabilites